Using Camera.setViewOffset with Reflector stretches the reflected texture in three.js
I’m trying to move the scene without changing perspective with the camera.setViewOffset function.
However, when using Reflector, if set the offset x value above a certain level, the reflected texture is stretched.
The offset y value does not seem to be affected.
Reflector
Here’s a fiddle. You can see this by adjusting the gui on the right.
https://jsfiddle.net/corely/g720m8th/1/
import { Reflector } from 'three/addons/objects/Reflector.js';

const groundMirror = new Reflector(new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100, 100), {
    clipBias: 0.003,
    textureWidth: window.innerWidth * window.devicePixelRatio,
    textureHeight: window.innerHeight * window.devicePixelRatio,
    color: 0xb5b5b5
});
groundMirror.rotation.x = -Math.PI / 2;
scene.add(groundMirror);

const offset = { x: -window.innerWidth * 0.45, y: 0 };

function setViewOffset () {
  camera.setViewOffset(
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight,
    offset.x,
    offset.y,
    window.innerWidth,
    window.innerHeight
  );
  render();
}

Water2
And with Water2, the reflected texture is not stretched, but moves in the opposite direction of the object.
https://jsfiddle.net/corely/wkx9hbgv/1/
import { Water } from 'three/addons/objects/Water2.js';

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
const water = new Water( new THREE.PlaneGeometry( 500, 500 ), {
    color: 0xffffff,
    scale: 5,
    flowDirection: new THREE.Vector2( 0.1, 0.1 ),
    normalMap0: textureLoader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/water/Water_1_M_Normal.jpg' ),
    normalMap1: textureLoader.load( 'https://threejs.org/examples/textures/water/Water_2_M_Normal.jpg' )
});
water.rotateX( -Math.PI / 2 );
scene.add( water );

What did I miss?
How can I fix this?

I have encountered this issue as well and have been trying to solve it for almost two days without success. It appears that this comment and your post on the Three.js forum are the only instances where this problem has been noted. I am confident that it is related to the viewport and the rendering space, as it seems the Reflector camera's space is being clipped. I have also tried setting the offset in the Reflector camera but the problem is still there..
